# Image View is not a perfect circle

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a `UITableViewCell` which contains an `UIImageView`.

The image view should be a circle, so I made the cornerRadius equal to half of its height. The problem is that if the image is not big enough (the width/height constraints of the image view, not the image itself), it is not rounded correctly. If I increase the constraints, everything will work fine.

The image is a square and the image view also has a 1:1 ratio constraint. 
Any idea what the problem is?

[image]

I call this in `awakeFromNib`:

```
private func setUpCellDesign() {
    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.height / 2
    profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 15

}
```

I have noticed that it doesn't work as wanted even if I add other elements in the cell and try to round the corners in the same way (for example a button with rounded corners).

Comment: do you have constraints ? Set `maskToBounds = true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have an issue with the layout-subviews of the cell - you need a few more cycles of the auto-layout mechanism

You can solve it by overriding [layoutSubViews](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) and put the snip code you wrote in there.

> You should override this method only if the autoresizing and
>   constraint-based behaviors of the subviews do not offer the behavior
>   you want. You can use your implementation to set the frame rectangles
>   of your subviews directly.

Answer (score 1):

That's happening because the corner radius is greater than `min(view.frame.width, view.frame.height) / 2`, and that is because `setUpCellDesign()` is being called before the cell has it's final frame.

What I would suggest would be to create a `UIImageView` subclass, I named mine `CircularImageView`, and implement it like this:

```
class CircularImageView: UIImageView {
  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    clipsToBounds = true
    layer.cornerRadius = min(frame.width, frame.height) / 2
  }
}
```

This will make sure that the image view will be as circular as possible no matter the size, and if it's a rectangle the corner radius will adapt to the shortest side to prevent that pointy corner you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Jsut call it in  `layoutSubviews` becuse all subview now have its real frame

```
  override func layoutSubviews() {
              super.layoutSubviews()
                profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.height / 2
            profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
            mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    }
```

Comment: viewWillLayoutSubviews is for view controller and not for OP question a cell

Comment: sorry `layoutSubviews` subviews in cell  see updated

Comment: If you  `override func layoutSubviews() ` please do call `super.layoutSubviews()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly the size of the image view you want to display, just use that size instead of calling it's `profileImageView.frame.height`. This will remove the need for overriding the `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: This is the lazy way to do it. If the image is proportional to the screen size, it will break, and if you want to change the image size at some point you'll have to make changes in two places. The code he has is already better than this answer, he just needs to call it at the right time.